# Reorganizing an array without sort() and doubles

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array like this named contents:

```
contents[0]='<button id=' + randomChar0 +' class="btn" onclick="check('+ f + randomChar0 + f +');">' + randomChar0 + '</Button>';
contents[1]='<button id=' + randomChar1 +' class="btn" onclick="check('+ f + randomChar1 + f +');">' + randomChar1 + '</Button>';
contents[2]='<button id=' + randomChar2 +' class="btn" onclick="check('+ f + randomChar2 + f +');">' + randomChar2 + '</Button>';
```

I have tried to rearrange it with this code:

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
};
```

calling it like this:

```
shuffle(contents);
```

from [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

But this Method gives me doubles quite often.

Any idea how to make sure the buttons always change their order without any doubling and without using `sort()`?

I want to rearrange the array to make the buttons in it appear in a different order everytime i output the array. I also dont want any of the buttons appear twice by accident, which means that i need ALL of the buttons to be output in a "random" order.

Update: I just found this [test of array shufflings](http://jsperf.com/array-shuffle-comparator/12), there are interesting results.

Comment: What do you mean by doubles? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well sort() is not really randomizing in a proper way, i admit its short an clean but if you check the random percentage on certain keys you weill see that its not all that random.

Comment: @doldt i am trying to rearrange the order of the buttons in the array without accidentally having one button be in there twice. The buttons are answers in a game so if they are always in the same spot the user has an easy win.

Comment: @tomalak from the post i referred to: [0]): 1 = 29.19%, 2 = 29.53%, 3 = 20.06%, 4 = 11.91%, 5 = 5.99%, 6 = 3.32%

Comment: @tomalak Using `.sort` to shuffle (atleast with your approach) does not yield great randomness... http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html

Comment: @rouby Already removed my comments.